# Why MMM moment month includes "."?

Tags: momentjs

I have this format `"YYYY. MMM. DD. HH:mm"` and it will show `2020. nov.. 15. 10:18`. why second "." is included?

Docs shows different examples here: https://momentjs.com

Comment: can you supply more of your code and better explain your setup.  my quick test does not have this issue http://jsfiddle.net/jy38vsnr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MMM is the format mask for abbreviated month. The string that is returned from the MMM format is adding a . to abbreviate the month.

The documentation you provided does not show a period probably because of the locale set on your environment. I would assume your locale has defined the short month to include the period as per the github issue linked here.

https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3662

Here is a jfiddle showing how I tested the format mask syntax you have provided. In my en-US browser it does not have an extra period.

http://jsfiddle.net/jy38vsnr/

```
var now = moment().format('YYYY. MMM. DD. HH:mm');
alert(now);
```